# search engine implementation with hibernate search and elastic search sample code

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I want to search engine like yahoo / google search. I have my oracle database. I want create a simple Spring Rest base webapp with one search component where i can give my input like `xyz` based on the input it should give me suggestion from Oracle database.

After all my deep analysis i found that HibernateSearch ORM 5.9.1 which will help for this requirement because it can be integrate with Elastic Search too. So, i have decided to build my webapp with HibernateSearch along with ElasticSearch.

But i couldnt found any sample webapp for this. I just want to refer some piece of code or an idea how to integrate in following files

```
hibernate.cfg.xml  
POJO classes
App.java class
```

Comment: Google found this: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hibernate-search-example/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using Hibernate You can use Spring Data to Connect to ElasticSearch.

Use this as Sample Project.

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-elasticsearch-example/

For Hibernate and ElasticSearch you can refer to this Url

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html/ch11.html#_built_in_or_server_defined_analyzers

Answer (score 0):

You can find testing templates and simple demos in the Hibernate repositories:

- [Integration testing example](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-elasticsearch/hibernate-search-elasticsearch-5)
- [Two runnable demos](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-demos/tree/master/hibernate-search)

You might also want to read [Getting started with Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/).